# getting the error when using tableview function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The program is building successfully, but when it goes into the simulation, it crashes, and the fatal error message is logged to console.

The line that triggers the error is:

```
let cell = self.tableview?.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

[image]

Comment: Have you registered `CustomCell` with that identifier?

Comment: Does your tableView contains a cell with class 'CustomCell' and reusable identifier 'cell'?

Comment: @Scriptable yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is cell returning nil? You need to make sure that you're passing the correct identifier of the UITableViewCell in your storyboard to the `withIdentifier: "cell"` parameter. Also, what is being logged to the console when you get this error? Many times it will point to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give same identifier "cell" in storyboard.